# Using C# String.Format "{0:p0}" without the leading space before percentage sign

Tags: c#, string

Using the expression

```
String.Format("{0:p0}",0.10) gives 10 %
```

How do I get this to return `10%` (without the space between 10 and %)?

Culture: en-GB

Answer (score 91, accepted):

`String.Format("{0:0%}", 0.10)`

Answer (score 36):

Use the [NumberFormatInfo.PercentPositivePattern Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.percentpositivepattern%28v=vs.96%29.aspx):

```
NumberFormatInfo numberInfo = new NumberFormatInfo();
numberInfo.PercentPositivePattern = 1;
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", 0.10.ToString("P0",numberInfo)));
```

Comment: Cannot be used in XAML.

Comment: The name of this prop is so weird.. but it does the job thx !

Answer (score 12):

If you're OK with not using `Format()` you could do `0.10F.ToString("0%");`.

Comment: `0.00%` if you want two decimals.

Comment: `String.Format("{0:0%}", .10F)` will work. `Double.ToString(format)` uses the same formatting system.

Answer (score 7):

Only enhancing @Jay Riggs response, and because i don´t have enough reputation just to comment, i´d go with:

```
String.Format(numberInfo, "{0:p0}", 0.10);
```

I think this way you cover situations where you have to format more than one value:

```
String.Format(numberInfo, "{0:p0} {1:p0}", 0.10, 0.20);
```

Answer (score 5):

Change the culture info.

For some cultures it displays %10 , % 10 , 10 % , 10% , .1 , .10 , 0.1 , 0.10 ...

I will check which CultureInfo gives you "10%"

Comment: This is the correct answer. Using a custom format string here will break any globalization you may want to support in the future.

Answer (score 4):

With a decimal point as well.

```
String.Format("{0:0.0%}", 0.6493072393590115)
```

Answer = 64.9%

Answer (score 3):

To add to the other answers, here's the relevant documentation:

- [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

```
String.Format("{0:p0}",0.10).Replace(" ","");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

0.1.ToString("0%")