# Correct string formatting (or rounding)

Tags: c#, formatting

```
var rounded = Math.Round(value, 1);
string prob = string.Format("{0:P}", rounded);
```

**Example:**

```
value : 0.599..
rounded: 0.6
prob : 60.00 %
```

I want the prob to be just 60 % How can I do this?

Comment: Try `{0:P0}` to indicate that you do not want any values after the decimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `{0:0%}` if you want "60%" [without a space between the number and percent symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229087/using-c-sharp-string-format-0p0-without-the-leading-space-before-percentage).

Use `{0:P0}` if you want "60 %" with a space.

```
var value = 0.599;
var rounded = Math.Round(value, 1);

string prob1 = string.Format("{0:0%}", rounded);
Console.WriteLine(prob1);
// prints "60%"

string prob2 = string.Format("{0:P0}", rounded);
Console.WriteLine(prob2);
// prints "60 %"
```

Comment: P0 doesn't add a space for me.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/1vZsJk